# Two different xmls and one xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files which use one xsl
Only difference in these xml files is first file has `<Valuation>` element and second xml has `<NadaDualValuation>` and a child `<mar:Valuation>` element

I want to get data in `<AICOption>` element, there are multiple ComparableVehicleRecord.

So for first xml I have

```
<xsl:for-each select="/df:ValuationReport/df:Valuation/mar:CVDBValuationData/mar:ComparableVehicleRecord[$ComparableNo]/typ2:AICOption">
```

I'm new to XSLT, Please suggest how can I make this same line work for second xml too.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please don't post partial code: we cannot see you your namespace declarations and you are using an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="
df:ValuationReport/df:Valuation/mar:CVDBValuationData/mar:ComparableVehicleRecord/typ2:AICOption | df:ValuationReport/df:NADADualValuation/mar:Valuation/mar:CVDBValuationData/mar:ComparableVehicleRecord/typ2:AICOption">
```

Comment: you removed '/' before df:ValuationReport, will it still find that element?

Comment: @user3904811 Yes, assuming you are in the context of `/` - as you would be, if you started by `<xsl:template match="/">`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all of the `AICOption` elements regardless of their ancestral context,

```
<xsl:for-each select="//typ2:AICOption">
```

will abstract over the contextual differences and work for both files.

If you need some context, you may still be able to use `//` above the point where the context matters:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//mar:ComparableVehicleRecord[$ComparableNo]/typ2:AICOption">
```

The general idea is that `//` selects among all descendents (and self), so you can use it above the context that matters so that your XPath will work with both of your files.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, I try to avoid the `//` operator whenever possible (i.e. when the exact path is known) in order to improve performance by reducing the scope.

Comment: Sure, that's a good rule of thumb, especially when so many questions and answers throw `//` around without knowing what it means.  Here, though, is a chance apply it purposefully to skip over varying context and meet OP's needs elegantly.